# Soundcloud javascript SDK is giving 404 - not found

Tags: javascript, sdk, http-status-code-404, soundcloud

I just noticed that my web app that has a `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
```

is no longer loading the javascript file.  The network panel is showing "404 Not Found"

I also just entered the url `https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js` in my browser, but I'm seeing a blank page.

Is something wrong with what I'm doing? Maybe the URL is not up to date?  I'm following the "basic use" instructions at https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

Here's a jsfiddle that only has the script loading tag.  In the javascript console you'll see that it fails to load:
http://jsfiddle.net/dn0m23rs/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, it seemed to just have been a temporary outage.  Sadly, nothing was indicated on the soundcloud status blog.